# translate Growing Recursion to Iteration?

Tags: java, python, recursion

I am writing a program for a process in Minecraft, it's supposed to edit the world and "clean it up" by replacing the blocks you can't see.

So the situation is a 3D world of cubic blocks. The program needs to identify a body of air and propagate in all directions from each block to see if there's more air touching it. I wrote a recursive function in jython used in conjunction with MCEdit (jython is basically a bridge between java and python).

The source of the problem is that each call creates 5 new ones.
An example function:

```
def checkAir(coordinate):
    #check if there's air and if so, add to a list
    for direction in directions:
        nextCoordinate = direction.increment(coordinate)
        checkAir(nextCoordinate)
```

The function is much more complicated in reality. Among other things, before moving on, it will make sure it doesn't go back to the coordinate it just came from, and it checks a list containing the coordinates of the air body to see if it's already there. If so, it will not make more recursive calls.

So the source of the problem is a RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. AKA StackOverflow.

I want to know how I could write this program with a more iterative approach, to prevent the stackoverflow error. If you don't know python, I don't mind java at all. I can translate it myself. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35840635/1553851) a while ago for a similar question. It uses a stack object to simulate recursion. You might be able to do something similar here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data structures such as stacks to pass from recursive algorithms to iterative algorithms:

```
Stack<Object> stack;
stack.push(first_object);
while( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
   // Do something
   my_object = stack.pop();

  // Push other objects on the stack.

}
```

Comment: I did end up with a while loop that iterates over the locations recorded in the last pass of the while loop. It's probably similar but I used a Set, not a Stack. I wonder if that's more performant! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In your case, the set is better because you don't want to iterate duplicate locations. A Stack is more general, and the usual implementation for its "push" and "pull".

Comment: I did end up using his solution with a python list, which has the same functionality as the stack, and I later replaced it with a set because of the reason you stated and because that also has a pop() method. Thanks for the help!